# Convert date format from Y-m-d H:i:s into dmy

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date time in string with format `Y-m-d H:i:s` like this:

```
$dateTime = '2018-07-06 18:53:21';
```

i want to conver it into dmy format, like this:

```
$convertedDateTime = $this->convertDateTime($dateTime);
echo $convertedDateTime;
```

and the result i expected from above `echo` is **060718**, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Simply use  `date_format($date,'dmy');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2018-07-06 18:53:21')->format('dmy');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `date_format` like this:

```
echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");  //e.g. 2013/03/15 00:00:00
echo date_format($date,"dmy");   //e.g. 150313    -- Y capital would return 2013
```

Comment: ah yeah, forgot about date_format - nice and clean :)

Comment: got this error: `Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in`

Comment: your are passing string instead of date, in your case you will pass $convertedDateTime as the parameter

Answer (score 2):

there's two methods to use:

`date` - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

usage example:

```
$myDate = '2018-07-06 09:49:00';
$myDate = date('d-m-y', strtotime($myDate));
```

but more often than not you'll want to use DateTime https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php:

```
$myDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2018-07-06 09:49:00');
$$newDate = $myDate->format('d-m-Y');
```